# Error running HelloCpp Cocos2d-x example on Android Unable to load assets

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I am currently attempting to get Cocos2d-x 2.2.2 working on my Windows machine. I am trying to upload the HelloCpp sample project to my Galaxy S4 through Eclipse. I am getting the follow error from logcat:

> [2014-01-22 16:29:24 - HelloCpp]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due
>   to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*') [2014-01-22 16:29:24 - HelloCpp] 
>   Unable to add
>   'K:\Cocos2d\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\assets\app.icf':
>   Zip add failed [2014-01-22 16:29:24 - HelloCpp] ERROR: unable to
>   process assets while packaging
>   'K:\Cocos2d\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
>   [2014-01-22 16:29:24 - HelloCpp] ERROR: packaging of
>   'K:\Cocos2d\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
>   failed

I have seen similar errors where the space in Marker Felt is the cause but the solution to that doesnt apply here as there is no space in app.icf.

Why is this error occuring and how could i fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of time this`(resources.ap_)` problem occur when there is `permission problem` i.e. it has `no permission to access` the file. You have to `take administrator permission` of the drive where your project exist.

You can check when you try to see the any image in the asset folder then it say `invalid photo` or it will not opened and say `permission denied`

Comment: I was able to get HelloCpp uloaded to my phone by putting chmod 777 in the build_native.sh. However, now when I use create_project.py to make a new cocos2dx project I am given no permission in any of that projects folders. How can I give myself permission to everything on my drive?